# ActiveMQ - hang in send method

Tags: activemq-classic, send, freeze

I'm using AcitveMQ 5.3. I don't know why my client hanged in send(of MessageProducer) method.

Here is my situation, 
I had a server(with a MQ broker), and I upgraded the server from 1.0 to 2.0 (the MQ broker was also upgraded from 5.3 to 5.6). 
At the same time, clients got a "Interupted" notification and a "Resume" notification due to the MQ broker restarted. In the "Resume", I sent my client status to the server and the it hanged.

I have 10 clients, and two of them have above situation. I have tried to restart MQ broker while i sent a message to the broker.(A similar scenario as above.) However, it's hard to reproduce.

Have anyone had this kind of experience? hanging in the send of MessageProducer method?

Thanks.

---

Update:
Here are the steps,

1. The broker and the clients version is  5.3
2. uninstall the broker and install 5.6 broker.

   ==> as you said, the version between broker and clients is not matched. Version mismatched will cause problems? But it should have backward compatibility, right?
3. I'll get Interrupted and Resume methods of TransportListener
4. I do some connection recovery tasks and also send a message to the broker in the Resume call

   ==> as you mentioned, it is a dangerous that send a message in Resume call. However, we did this all the time and never had this kind of issue before.
5. my program will hang in MessageProducer send.

Is that more clear? code are separated everywhere, it's not easy to post it.

Thanks.

---

update part2,

I move MessageProducer send to another thread, but I wait in Resume callback of TransportListener until sending done. In this scenario, it always hangs on sending a message. However, "sending a message in Resume callback directly" hangs occasionally. These two scenario is quite similar. Why are they so different? I dug in the source code(ActiveMQ-Cpp 3.4.5), but i didn't find any special things. or I dug in wrong files? I really want to know it's mechanism.

BTW, before "update part2", i'm using java version MQ. But the result seems no difference between java and cpp. So, at "update part2", i'm using ActiveMQ-CPP 3.4.5 as my library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit unclear what your setup is, are the clients and broker versions matched or not?  If not then the problem is most likely related to that.

Some code would be helpful here.  But I think what you are saying is that you send a message to the broker during the TransportListener method resumed() call.  This can be dangerous as you are looping back into the Transport layer from the same thread which generally lead to issues as these events aren't really meant to be places where you send messages etc but more for an update point which can allow you to kick off a new thread or activity to deal with connection recovery.

Hanging in MessageProducer send can be triggered in the case of Producer flow control kicking in as well but I'm not convinced this is happening in your case but without further clarification of you question its hard to say for sure.

Comment: In your case my answer stands, in production don't mistmatch client and broker versions unless you want to have a bad time.  Don't send in the transport event callback unless you want to have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another question, is it also dangerous to send in the MessageListener event callback(like, onMessage)?

Comment: In general no, this event is not called using the thread of the failover transport or its reconnect task.

Comment: Sorry, I found another issue and updated in my post, "update part2". Please help to reply. Thanks.